# Error when casting same type

Tags: c#, .net, casting, runtime-error

It is weird, it seems that the error is that can not cast one object to the same type.

What is even more infuriating is that the errors only occurs with one computer out of three that I have to test.

> [A]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DotSpatial.Controls.Header.ToolstripPosition]
>   no puede convertirse en
>   [B]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DotSpatial.Controls.Header.ToolstripPosition].
>   El tipo A se origina a partir de 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' en el contexto
>   'LoadNeither' en la ubicación
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   El tipo B se origina a partir de 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' en el contexto
>   'LoadNeither' en la ubicación
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.

Note that the PublicKeyToken of type A and B, and The Classname and even the assembly used seems to be the same.

What can cause this error?

Comment: This can be caused by having old versions of your dll in the bin folder. Delete it completely and rebuild.

Comment: @Rob already did that. I delete all bin folder. And the error is still the same. I even took the compiled version of one computer where it works correctly, run the program in the computer with issues, and I got the same error. (the exact same executable folder was tested in three computers, in two worked, in the other didn't)